# django registering models with many-to-many circular reference on Admin

Tags: django

This is how my models looks like:

```
class GameStates(models.Model):
    state_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    allowed_states = models.ManyToManyField('GameStates', related_name='allowed_states_admin')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.state_code
```

`allowed_states` has a `many-to-many` circular reference with `GameStates`. This field contains following information: Given a current state that the user is in, what are the other states that he is allowed to go.

I am trying to register this model on `Admin` as follows:

```
class GameStatesInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = GameStates.allowed_states.through


@admin.register(GameStates)
class GameStatesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [GameStatesInline]
    exclude = ('allowed_states',)
```

However, I keep getting the following error message:
`GameStates_allowed_states' has more than one ForeignKey to 'GameStates'.`

Would appreciate your help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create ManyToManyField from Model1 to Model2, the through table will have one ForeignKey to Model1 and one ForeignKey to Model2.

Since you are creating ManyToManyField from GameStates to GameStates, the through table will have 2 ForeignKeys to GameStates.  This model class can't be prepared unless these ForeignKey relationships have a 'related_name'.

If you generate through table with "GameStates.allowed_states.through" it won't have the related name for the ForeignKey fields.

I think you need to define through table by [writing another class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) and specifying related_name in ForeignKeys of the model corresponding to through table

```
class AllowedStates(models.Model):
    game_state = models.ForeignKey('GameState', related_name='something')
    allowed_state = models.ForeignKey('GameState', related_name='something_else')
```

And you can register AllowedStates in Admin

Comment: Hi Vinayak, can you please elaborate further on what you mean by creating another class? Can you please share some sample code that can help me get started? Thanks.

Comment: @TheWanderer I have edited the answer.  I hope it's more clear now.